# Spring Boot Start Up error java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I created a new Spring Started project from the online spring boot application generator and getting below Spring Boot Start Up error which is Caused by java.util.zip.ZipException invalid stored block lengths

org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[paymentbatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
            ... 40 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
            at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164) ~

Answer (score 2):

Some problem in the maven dependencies being corrupted. Deleting maven repository and rebuilding (mvn clean install) the app fixed the issue.

Comment: Same as here. mvn clean install (without deleting maven repo) fixed. Please accept your answer :)